# no matches for kind "Config" in version "v1"

Tags: kubernetes, config, minikube, falco

I tried to run a config file to set Falco as my backend webhook. Iam getting this error on trying to run my config file

```
revaa@revaa-Lenovo-E41-25:~/opa$ kubectl apply -f conflc.yaml
error: unable to recognize "conflc.yaml": no matches for kind "Config" in version "v1"
```

Here is my config file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: falco
  cluster:
    server: http://$FALCO_SERVICE_CLUSTERIP:8765/k8s_audit
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: falco
    user: ""
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
preferences: {}
users: []
```

How to fix this?

Comment: afaik, there is no kind named `Config` in vanilla Kubernetes. Are you using a cloud provider?

Comment: Iam using minikube

Answer (score 0):

The object `Config` is not a server side configuration. Instead, it is used for your kubectl (in general) to know where it should interact with.

You can check out the documentation about context [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/). This will let you understand how to manage the cluster with the object `Object` inside your local machine.

In the case that you want to add the configuration to your application, what you need is the `ConfigMap`, which is the object under Kubernetes server side.

You can check out more information about `ConfigMap` in [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/).

Comment: I have use this config to set falco as my backend webhook . Iam following this tutorial https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-audit-log-falco/  Is there any other way to do the same?